# Setting default windows terminal starting directory to folder within c drive WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I am trying to set my default terminal for my WSL prompt in windows terminal to start at a specific folder under the C drive.

i am able to set the default to `/mnt` but it wont let me go `/mnt/c/<myfolder>` whenever i do this is sets it back to `/mnt/c/Users/<myuser>`

Comment: What does your profile for that shell look like in `settings.json`?

Comment: setting `startingDirectory` to `C:\\<myfolder` in `settings.json` may solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

In `settings.json` if you are using the `commandline` property replace that line with:

`"source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl"`

Then set the value of your startingDirectory to where ever you like in the C drive using the drive letter and forward slashes in the path, so it will look something like this:

`"startingDirectory" : "C:/Windows/Fonts",`